# In jQuery, hide any :visible data div and show $(this) clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a calendar where the tables are built out weekly. Each week has a designated data point: along with the days. When I click on a day, I want to display the details between weeks.

The **issue I am running into**  is when I click on a day I want to only display the current days details. With the current code it hides all days. When I remove `$('.day).hide();` It shows everything.

I want to hide all days then just show the current one I clicked on.

I made a **[Demo Page](http://codepen.io/whosdustin/pen/kKaAr)** on CodePen.

**/ Code Below /**

## HTML

---

```
<table class="week" data-week="second">
    <tr>
       <td data-day="7">
            <a>7</a>
            <div class="events">
                <label class="info">Hi There</label>
            </div>
       </td>
       <td data-day="8">
            <a>8</a>
            <div class="events">
                <label class="info">Hi There</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="details" data-week="second">
    <div class="day" data-day="7">
        Day 7 Details
    </div>
    <div class="day" data-day="8">
        Day 8 Details
    </div>
</div>
```

## Javascript

---

```
$(".week, .week td").on("click", function () {
   var dow = $(this).data('day');
   var wom = $(this).data('week');

   $('.day').hide();
   $('.day[data-day=' + dow + ']').show();
   $('.details[data-week=' + wom + ']').slideToggle(500); 
});
```

I made a **[Demo Page](http://codepen.io/whosdustin/pen/kKaAr)** on CodePen.

Comment: your code has a missing `'` `$('.day).hide();`

Comment: I fixed that in my post. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial selector should not have '.week' by itself. Also missing the hide.
Try this:

```
$(".week td").on("click", function (e) {
    var dow = $(this).data('day');
    var wom = $(this).closest('.week').data('week');
    $(".details").slideUp(500);
    $('.day').hide();
    $('.day[data-day="' + dow + '"]').show();
    $('.details[data-week=' + wom + ']').slideToggle(500); 
});
```

**Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ufiDv)**

Comment: This is correct. The reason is that the event "bubbles" up to the table `.week` and the days get hidden again, but this time `dow` is undefined...